# Why do we need monads?

Tags: haskell, monads

In my humble opinion the answers to the famous question ["What is a monad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad), especially the most voted ones, try to explain what is a monad without clearly explaining *why monads are really necessary*.  Can they be explained as the solution to a problem?

Comment: http://cs.coloradocollege.edu/~bylvisaker/MonadMotivation/

Comment: http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html

Comment: What research have you already done?  Where have you looked?  What resources have you found?  [We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, and show us in the question what research you've done](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/781723).  There are many resources that try to explain the motivation for resources -- if you haven't found any at all, you might need to do a little more research.  If you've found some but they didn't help you, it would make this a better question if you explained what you'd found and why specifically they didn't work for you.

Comment: This is definitely a better fit for Programmers.StackExchange and not a good fit for StackOverflow. I'd vote to migrate if I could, but I can't. =(

Comment: Because there is syntactic sugar associated with them.

Comment: Since you [posted related to this on Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247653/are-moderators-expert-in-every-subject), please don't continue to 'argue' about it here.

Comment: @jpmc26 Most likely it would get closed there as "primarily opinion-based"; here it at least stands a chance (as shown by the huge number of upvotes, rapid reopen yesterday, and no more close votes yet)

Comment: For future people coming here, take a look at this great lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=re96UgMk6GQ. You can start at 31:47 (and watch ~10-15 minutes), but I would recommend watching the whole thing as it is a great lecture.

Answer (score 641, accepted):

### Why do we need monads?

1. We want to program **only using functions**. ("functional programming (FP)" after all).
2. Then, we have a first big problem. This is a program:

   `f(x) = 2 * x`

   `g(x,y) = x / y`

   How can we say  **what is to be executed first**? How can we form an ordered sequence of functions (i.e. **a program**) *using no more than functions*?

   Solution: **compose functions**. If you want first `g` and then `f`, just write `f(g(x,y))`. This way, "the program" is a function as well: `main = f(g(x,y))`. OK, but ...
3. More problems: some functions **might fail** (i.e. `g(2,0)`, divide by 0). We have **no "exceptions"** in FP (an exception is not a function). How do we solve it?

   Solution: Let's **allow functions to return two kind of things**: instead of having `g : Real,Real -> Real` (function from two reals into a real), let's allow `g : Real,Real -> Real | Nothing` (function from two reals into (real or nothing)).
4. But functions should (to be simpler) return only **one thing**.

   Solution: let's create a new type of data to be returned, a "**boxing type**" that encloses maybe a real or be simply nothing. Hence, we can have `g : Real,Real -> Maybe Real`. OK, but ...
5. What happens now to `f(g(x,y))`? `f` is not ready to consume a `Maybe Real`. And, we don't want to change every function we could connect with `g` to consume a `Maybe Real`.

   Solution: let's **have a special function to "connect"/"compose"/"link" functions**. That way, we can, behind the scenes, adapt the output of one function to feed the following one.

   In our case:  `g >>= f` (connect/compose `g` to `f`). We want `>>=` to get `g`'s output, inspect it and, in case it is `Nothing` just don't call `f` and return `Nothing`; or on the contrary, extract the boxed `Real` and feed `f` with it. (This algorithm is just the implementation of `>>=` for the `Maybe` type). Also note that `>>=` must be written **only once** per "boxing type" (different box, different adapting algorithm).
6. Many other problems arise which can be solved using this same pattern: 1. Use a "box" to codify/store different meanings/values, and have functions like `g` that return those "boxed values". 2. Have a composer/linker `g >>= f` to help connecting `g`'s output to `f`'s input, so we don't have to change any `f` at all.
7. Remarkable problems that can be solved using this technique are:

   - having a global state that every function in the sequence of functions ("the program") can share: solution `StateMonad`.
   - We don't like "impure functions": functions that yield *different* output for *same* input. Therefore, let's mark those functions, making them to return a tagged/boxed value: `IO` monad.

Total happiness!

Comment: @Carl Please write a better answer to enlighten us

Comment: @Carl I think that it is clear in the answer that there are many many problems that benefit from this pattern (point 6) and that `IO` monad is just one more problem in the list `IO` (point 7). On the other hand `IO` only appears once and at the end, so, don't understand your "most of its time talking ... about IO".

Comment: Does `>>=` have to be written once per (f,g,Monad) or (g,Monad)?

Comment: @yurez Only per monad. If you want a class to be a monad you have to define for it `>>=` and `return`. I.E                                                                   `class Monad m where  
    return :: a -> m a  
    (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b `    (See: http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads)

Comment: Function composition doesn't determine which function is executed first (i.e. writing `\x y -> f (g x y)` doesn't mean that `g` will be executed before `f`). That is determined by the evaluation strategy. To prove this evaluate the following in GHCi, `let assert = const True . error` and `assert "Function composition doesn't determine evaluation order."` The result is `True`, not an error. In a strict language it would throw an error. However because Haskell is non-strict by default it doesn't do so. Instead it evaluates `const` first and doesn't evaluate `error` at all.

Comment: @AaditMShah "The exception confirms the rule"

Comment: @cibercitizen1 That's a weak excuse for when you don't know what the rule is :)

Comment: @BartoszKP  In `const True . error` Does `const True` depends on `error`? Great example to prove what? That if you compose functions in which don't depend the outer function on the inner function's output, the inner one doesn't need to be evaluated? Great ;-)

Comment: @cibercitizen1 I didn't say anything about `const True .error`, nor about any dependencies nor about composing functions. I don't know whether you're right or wrong. I've only evaluated your previously expressed argument.

Comment: @carl not just IO, but it just happens that Monads (already known to the math people) provides a way to address *several* of the "hard parts" of pure functional programming, and the State hard part pretty much solves everything else. So, one set of syntactic sugar gives a lot of benefits. It is, in essence, adding stateful things into Haskell in a palletable manner.

Comment: The great misconceptions about monads: monads about state; monads about exception handling; there is no way to implement IO in pure FPL without monads;monads are unambiguous (contrargument is `Either`). The most of answer is about "Why do we need functors?".

Comment: *"6. 2. Have a composer/linker `g >>= f` to help connecting `g`'s output to `f`'s input, so we don't have to change any `f` at all."* **this is not right** at all. Before, in `f(g(x,y))`, `f` could produce anything. It could be `f:: Real -> String`. With "monadic composition" **it must be changed** to produce `Maybe String`, or else the types won't fit. Moreover, **`>>=`** itself **doesn't fit**!! It's `>=>` that does this composition, not `>>=`. See the discussion with dfeuer under Carl's answer.

Comment: Your answer is right in the sense that monads IMO indeed are best described as being about the composition/ality of "functions" (Kleisli arrows really), but the precise details of what type goes where are what makes them "monads". you could wire the boxes in all kinds of manners (like Functor, etc.). This *specific* way of wiring them together is what defines "the monad".

Comment: For anyone learning Scala, the equivalent of the compose function (`>>=`) in Scala is usually the `map` method. For example, `Option.map` will apply the given function to the boxed in data if the type is `Some` and do nothing if the type if `None`. So instead of `g >>= f`, we'd use `g map f`. The `Try` monad works similarly, but `Failure` will store an exception (and calling map on a `Failure` returns the unmodified `Failure`).

Comment: I wish I had seen this answer years ago. It's sooooo much clearer than anything else I've read. Makes the point, and language-agnostic too. Thanks very much!

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Glad to be helpful. Best of luck.

Comment: _let's mark those functions, making them to return a tagged/boxed value: IO monad._, why not just marking those functions/operators which are going to have side effects in the language and let the programmer know and decide when and where and how s/he uses it, e.g. `a_dangerous_function_with_side_effect`? Do we then still need the whole monad story for having side effects possibility?

Answer (score 240):

The answer is, of course, **"We don't"**. As with all abstractions, it isn't necessary.

Haskell does not need a monad abstraction. It isn't necessary for performing IO in a pure language. The `IO` type takes care of that just fine by itself. The existing monadic desugaring of `do` blocks could be replaced with desugaring to `bindIO`, `returnIO`, and `failIO` as defined in the `GHC.Base` module. (It's not a documented module on hackage, so I'll have to point at [its source](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/f006ed7965a0fa918d720cc387b33cb8e7083854/libraries/base/GHC/Base.hs#L1063) for documentation.) So no, there's no need for the monad abstraction.

So if it's not needed, why does it exist? Because it was found that many patterns of computation form monadic structures. Abstraction of a structure allows for writing code that works across all instances of that structure. To put it more concisely - code reuse.

In functional languages, the most powerful tool found for code reuse has been composition of functions. The good old `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)` operator is exceedingly powerful. It makes it easy to write tiny functions and glue them together with minimal syntactic or semantic overhead.

But there are cases when the types don't work out quite right.  What do you do when you have `foo :: (b -> Maybe c)` and `bar :: (a -> Maybe b)`? `foo . bar` doesn't typecheck, because `b` and `Maybe b` aren't the same type.

But... it's almost right. You just want a bit of leeway. You want to be able to treat `Maybe b` as if it were basically `b`. It's a poor idea to just flat-out treat them as the same type, though. That's more or less the same thing as null pointers, which Tony Hoare famously called [the billion-dollar mistake](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare). So if you can't treat them as the same type, maybe you can find a way to extend the composition mechanism `(.)` provides.

In that case, it's important to really examine the theory underlying `(.)`. Fortunately, someone has already done this for us. It turns out that the combination of `(.)` and `id` form a mathematical construct known as a [category](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/11/04/category-the-essence-of-composition/). But there are other ways to form categories. A Kleisli category, for instance, allows the objects being composed to be augmented a bit. A Kleisli category for `Maybe` would consist of `(.) :: (b -> Maybe c) -> (a -> Maybe b) -> (a -> Maybe c)` and `id :: a -> Maybe a`. That is, the objects in the category augment the `(->)` with a `Maybe`, so `(a -> b)` becomes `(a -> Maybe b)`.

And suddenly, we've extended the power of composition to things that the traditional `(.)` operation doesn't work on. This is a source of new abstraction power. Kleisli categories work with more types than just `Maybe`. They work with every type that can assemble a proper category, obeying the category laws.

1. Left identity: `id . f` = `f`
2. Right identity: `f . id` = `f`
3. Associativity: `f . (g . h)` = `(f . g) . h`

As long as you can prove that your type obeys those three laws, you can turn it into a Kleisli category. And what's the big deal about that? Well, it turns out that monads are exactly the same thing as Kleisli categories. `Monad`'s `return` is the same as Kleisli `id`. `Monad`'s `(>>=)` isn't identical to Kleisli `(.)`, but it turns out to be very easy to write each in terms of the other. And the category laws are the same as the monad laws, when you translate them across the difference between `(>>=)` and `(.)`.

So why go through all this bother? Why have a `Monad` abstraction in the language? As I alluded to above, it enables code reuse. It even enables code reuse along two different dimensions.

The first dimension of code reuse comes directly from the presence of the abstraction. You can write code that works across all instances of the abstraction. There's the entire [monad-loops](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops) package consisting of loops that work with any instance of `Monad`.

The second dimension is indirect, but it follows from the existence of composition. When composition is easy, it's natural to write code in small, reusable chunks. This is the same way having the `(.)` operator for functions encourages writing small, reusable functions.

So why does the abstraction exist? Because it's proven to be a tool that enables more composition in code, resulting in creating reusable code and encouraging the creation of more reusable code. Code reuse is one of the holy grails of programming. The monad abstraction exists because it moves us a little bit towards that holy grail.

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between categories generally and Kleisli categories? The three laws you describe hold in any category.

Comment: @dfeuer Oh.  To put it in code, `newtype Kleisli m a b = Kleisli (a -> m b)`. Kleisli categories are functions where the categorical return type (`b` in this case) is the argument to a type constructor `m`. Iff `Kleisli m` forms a category, `m` is a Monad.

Comment: What is a categorical return type exactly? `Kleisli m` seems to form a category whose objects are Haskell types and such that the arrows from `a` to `b` are the functions from `a` to `m b`, with `id = return` and `(.) = (<=<)`. Is that about right, or am I mixing up different levels of things or something?

Comment: @dfeuer That's correct. The objects are all types, and the morphisms are between types `a` and `b`, but they're not simple functions. They're decorated with an extra `m` in the return value of the function.

Comment: Is the Category Theory terminology really needed?  Maybe, Haskell would be easier if you turned the types into pictures where the type would be the DNA for how the pictures are drawn (dependent types though*), and then you use the picture to write your program with the names being small ruby characters above the icon.

Answer (score 24):

Benjamin Pierce said in [TAPL](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/)

> A type system can be regarded as calculating a kind of static
>   approximation to the run-time behaviours of the terms in a program.

That's why a language equipped with a powerful type system is strictly more expressive, than a poorly typed language. You can think about monads in the same way.

As @Carl and [sigfpe](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html) point, you can equip a datatype with all operations you want without resorting to monads, typeclasses or whatever other abstract stuff. However monads allow you not only to write reusable code, but also to abstract away all redundant detailes.

As an example, let's say we want to filter a list. The simplest way is to use the `filter` function: `filter (> 3) [1..10]`, which equals `[4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`.

A slightly more complicated version of `filter`, that also passes an accumulator from left to right, is

```
swap (x, y) = (y, x)
(.*) = (.) . (.)

filterAccum :: (a -> b -> (Bool, a)) -> a -> [b] -> [b]
filterAccum f a xs = [x | (x, True) <- zip xs $ snd $ mapAccumL (swap .* f) a xs]
```

To get all `i`, such that `i <= 10, sum [1..i] > 4, sum [1..i] < 25`, we can write

```
filterAccum (\a x -> let a' = a + x in (a' > 4 && a' < 25, a')) 0 [1..10]
```

which equals `[3,4,5,6]`.

Or we can redefine the `nub` function, that removes duplicate elements from a list, in terms of `filterAccum`:

```
nub' = filterAccum (\a x -> (x `notElem` a, x:a)) []
```

`nub' [1,2,4,5,4,3,1,8,9,4]` equals `[1,2,4,5,3,8,9]`. A list is passed as an accumulator here. The code works, because it's possible to leave the list monad, so the whole computation stays pure (`notElem` doesn't use `>>=` actually, but it could). However it's not possible to safely leave the IO monad (i.e. you cannot execute an IO action and return a pure value — the value always will be wrapped in the IO monad). Another example is mutable arrays: after you have leaved the ST monad, where a mutable array live, you cannot update the array in constant time anymore. So we need a monadic filtering from the `Control.Monad` module:

```
filterM          :: (Monad m) => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
filterM _ []     =  return []
filterM p (x:xs) =  do
   flg <- p x
   ys  <- filterM p xs
   return (if flg then x:ys else ys)
```

`filterM` executes a monadic action for all elements from a list, yielding elements, for which the monadic action returns `True`.

A filtering example with an array:

```
nub' xs = runST $ do
        arr <- newArray (1, 9) True :: ST s (STUArray s Int Bool)
        let p i = readArray arr i <* writeArray arr i False
        filterM p xs

main = print $ nub' [1,2,4,5,4,3,1,8,9,4]
```

prints `[1,2,4,5,3,8,9]` as expected.

And a version with the IO monad, which asks what elements to return:

```
main = filterM p [1,2,4,5] >>= print where
    p i = putStrLn ("return " ++ show i ++ "?") *> readLn
```

E.g.

```
return 1? -- output
True      -- input
return 2?
False
return 4?
False
return 5?
True
[1,5]     -- output
```

And as a final illustration, `filterAccum` can be defined in terms of `filterM`:

```
filterAccum f a xs = evalState (filterM (state . flip f) xs) a
```

with the `StateT` monad, that is used under the hood, being just an ordinary datatype.

This example illustrates, that monads not only allow you to abstract computational context and write clean reusable code (due to the composability of monads, as @Carl explains), but also to treat user-defined datatypes and built-in primitives uniformly.

Comment: This answer explains, why we need the Monad typeclass. The best way to understand, why we need monads and not something else, is to read about difference between monads and applicative functors: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342184/difference-between-monad-and-applicative-in-haskell), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409260/what-advantage-does-monad-give-us-over-an-applicative).

Answer (score 22):

*I don't think `IO` should be seen as a particularly outstanding monad, but it's certainly one of the more astounding ones for beginners, so I'll use it for my explanation.*

### Naïvely building an IO system for Haskell

The simplest conceivable IO system for a purely-functional language (and in fact the one Haskell started out with) is this:

```
main₀ :: String -> String
main₀ _ = "Hello World"
```

With lazyness, that simple signature is enough to actually build interactive terminal programs – *very* limited, though. Most frustrating is that we can only output text. What if we added some more exciting output possibilities?

```
data Output = TxtOutput String
            | Beep Frequency

main₁ :: String -> [Output]
main₁ _ = [ TxtOutput "Hello World"
          -- , Beep 440  -- for debugging
          ]
```

cute, but of course a much more realistic “alterative output” would be *writing to a file*. But then you'd also want some way to *read from* files. Any chance?

Well, when we take our `main₁` program and simply *pipe a file to the process* (using operating system facilities), we have essentially implemented file-reading. If we could trigger that file-reading from within the Haskell language...

```
readFile :: Filepath -> (String -> [Output]) -> [Output]
```

This would use an “interactive program” `String->[Output]`, feed it a string obtained from a file, and yield a non-interactive program that simply executes the given one.

There's one problem here: we don't really have a notion of *when* the file is read. The `[Output]` list sure gives a nice order to the *outputs*, but we don't get an order for when the *inputs* will be done.

Solution: make input-events also items in the list of things to do.

```
data IO₀ = TxtOut String
         | TxtIn (String -> [Output])
         | FileWrite FilePath String
         | FileRead FilePath (String -> [Output])
         | Beep Double

main₂ :: String -> [IO₀]
main₂ _ = [ FileRead "/dev/null" $ \_ ->
             [TxtOutput "Hello World"]
          ]
```

Ok, now you may spot an imbalance: you can read a file and make output dependent on it, but you can't use the file contents to decide to e.g. also read another file. Obvious solution: make the result of the input-events also something of type `IO`, not just `Output`. That sure includes simple text output, but also allows reading additional files etc..

```
data IO₁ = TxtOut String
         | TxtIn (String -> [IO₁])
         | FileWrite FilePath String
         | FileRead FilePath (String -> [IO₁])
         | Beep Double

main₃ :: String -> [IO₁]
main₃ _ = [ TxtIn $ \_ ->
             [TxtOut "Hello World"]
          ]
```

That would now actually allow you to express any file operation you might want in a program (though perhaps not with good performance), but it's somewhat overcomplicated:

- `main₃` yields a whole *list* of actions. Why don't we simply use the signature `:: IO₁`, which has this as a special case?
- The lists don't really give a reliable overview of program flow anymore: most subsequent computations will only be “announced” as the result of some input operation. So we might as well ditch the list structure, and simply cons a “and then do” to each output operation.

```
data IO₂ = TxtOut String IO₂
         | TxtIn (String -> IO₂)
         | Terminate

main₄ :: IO₂
main₄ = TxtIn $ \_ ->
         TxtOut "Hello World"
          Terminate
```

Not too bad!

### So what has all of this to do with monads?

In practice, you wouldn't want to use plain constructors to define all your programs. There would need to be a good couple of such fundamental constructors, yet for most higher-level stuff we would like to write a function with some nice high-level signature. It turns out most of these would look quite similar: accept some kind of meaningfully-typed value, and yield an IO action as the result.

```
getTime :: (UTCTime -> IO₂) -> IO₂
randomRIO :: Random r => (r,r) -> (r -> IO₂) -> IO₂
findFile :: RegEx -> (Maybe FilePath -> IO₂) -> IO₂
```

There's evidently a pattern here, and we'd better write it as

```
type IO₃ a = (a -> IO₂) -> IO₂    -- If this reminds you of continuation-passing
                                  -- style, you're right.

getTime :: IO₃ UTCTime
randomRIO :: Random r => (r,r) -> IO₃ r
findFile :: RegEx -> IO₃ (Maybe FilePath)
```

Now that starts to look familiar, but we're still only dealing with thinly-disguised plain functions under the hood, and that's risky: each “value-action” has the responsibility of actually passing on the resulting action of any contained function (else the control flow of the entire program is easily disrupted by one ill-behaved action in the middle). We'd better make that requirement explicit. Well, it turns out those are the *monad laws*, though I'm not sure we can really formulate them without the standard bind/join operators.

At any rate, we've now reached a formulation of IO that has a proper monad instance:

```
data IO₄ a = TxtOut String (IO₄ a)
           | TxtIn (String -> IO₄ a)
           | TerminateWith a

txtOut :: String -> IO₄ ()
txtOut s = TxtOut s $ TerminateWith ()

txtIn :: IO₄ String
txtIn = TxtIn $ TerminateWith

instance Functor IO₄ where
  fmap f (TerminateWith a) = TerminateWith $ f a
  fmap f (TxtIn g) = TxtIn $ fmap f . g
  fmap f (TxtOut s c) = TxtOut s $ fmap f c

instance Applicative IO₄ where
  pure = TerminateWith
  (<*>) = ap

instance Monad IO₄ where
  TerminateWith x >>= f = f x
  TxtOut s c >>= f = TxtOut s $ c >>= f
  TxtIn g >>= f = TxtIn $ (>>=f) . g
```

Obviously this is not an efficient implementation of IO, but it's in principle usable.

Comment: @jdlugosz: [`IO3 a ≡ Cont IO2 a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#t:Cont). But I meant that comment more as a nod to those who already know the continuation monad, as it doesn't exactly have a reputation as being beginner-friendly.

Answer (score 7):

Monads serve basically to compose functions together in a chain. Period.

Now the way they compose differs across the existing monads, thus resulting in different behaviors (e.g., to simulate mutable state in the state monad).

The confusion about monads is that being so general, i.e., a mechanism to compose functions, they can be used for many things, thus leading people to believe that monads are about state, about IO, etc, when they are only about "composing functions".

Now, one interesting thing about monads, is that the result of the composition is always of type "M a", that is, a value inside an envelope tagged with "M". This feature happens to be really nice to implement, for example, a clear separation between pure from impure code: declare all impure actions as functions of type "IO a" and provide no function, when defining the IO monad, to take out the "a" value from inside the "IO a". The result is that no function can be pure and at the same time take out a value from an "IO a", because there is no way to take such value while staying pure (the function must be inside the "IO" monad to use such value). (NOTE: well, nothing is perfect, so the "IO straitjacket" can be broken using "unsafePerformIO : IO a -> a" thus polluting what was supposed to be a pure function, but this should be used very sparingly and when you really know to be not introducing any impure code with side-effects.

Answer (score 5):

You need monads if you have a **type constructor** and **functions that returns values of that type family**. Eventually, you would like to **combine these kind of functions together**. These are the three key elements to answer *why*.

Let me elaborate. You have `Int`, `String` and `Real` and functions of type `Int -> String`, `String -> Real` and so on. You can combine these functions easily, ending with `Int -> Real`. Life is good.

Then, one day, you need to create a **new *family* of types**. It could be because you need to consider the possibility of returning no value (`Maybe`), returning an error (`Either`), multiple results (`List`) and so on.

Notice that `Maybe` is a type constructor. It takes a type, like `Int` and returns a new type `Maybe Int`. First thing to remember, **no type constructor, no monad.**

Of course, **you want to use your type constructor** in your code, and soon you end with functions like `Int -> Maybe String` and `String -> Maybe Float`. Now, you can't easily combine your functions. Life is not good anymore.

And here's when monads come to the rescue. They allow you to combine that kind of functions again. You just need to change the composition **.** for **>==**.

Comment: This has nothing to do with type families. What are you actually talking about?

Answer (score 5):

*Monads* are just a convenient framework for solving a class of recurring problems. First, monads must be *functors* (i.e. must support mapping without looking at the elements (or their type)), they must also bring a *binding* (or chaining) operation and a way to create a monadic value from an element type (`return`). Finally, `bind` and `return` must satisfy two equations (left and right identities), also called the monad laws. (Alternatively one could define monads to have a `flattening operation` instead of binding.)

The *list monad* is commonly used to deal with non-determinism. The bind operation selects one element of the list (intuitively all of them in *parallel worlds*), lets the programmer to do some computation with them, and then combines the results in all worlds to single list (by concatenating, or flattening, a nested list). Here is how one would define a permutation function in the monadic framework of Haskell:

```
perm [e] = [[e]]
perm l = do (leader, index) <- zip l [0 :: Int ..]
            let shortened = take index l ++ drop (index + 1) l
            trailer <- perm shortened
            return (leader : trailer)
```

Here is an example *repl* session:

```
*Main> perm "a"
["a"]
*Main> perm "ab"
["ab","ba"]
*Main> perm ""
[]
*Main> perm "abc"
["abc","acb","bac","bca","cab","cba"]
```

It should be noted that the list monad is in no way a side effecting computation. A mathematical structure being a monad (i.e. conforming to the above mentioned interfaces and laws) does not imply side effects, though side-effecting phenomena often nicely fit into the monadic framework.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do we need monadic types?

Since it was the quandary of I/O and its observable effects in nonstrict languages like Haskell that brought the monadic interface to such prominence:

- > [...] monads are used to address the more general problem of computations (involving state, input/output, backtracking, ...) returning values: they do not solve any input/output-problems directly but rather provide an elegant and flexible abstraction of many solutions to related problems. [...] For instance, no less than three different input/output-schemes are used to solve these basic problems in [Imperative functional programming](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.86.9725&rep=rep1&type=pdf), the paper which originally proposed *`a new model, based on monads, for performing input/output in a non-strict, [purely functional](http://conal.net/blog/posts/the-c-language-is-purely-functional) language'.* [...]
  >
  > [Such] input/output-schemes merely provide frameworks in which side-effecting operations can safely be used with a guaranteed order of execution and without affecting the properties of the purely functional parts of the language.
  >
  > [Claus Reinke](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.95.9846&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (pages 96-97 of 210).

  <sup>(emphasis by me.)</sup>
- > [...] When we write effectful code – monads or no monads – we have to constantly keep in mind the context of expressions we pass around.
  >
  > The fact that monadic code ‘desugars’ (is implementable in terms of) side-effect-free code is irrelevant. When we use monadic notation, we program within that notation – without considering what this notation desugars into. Thinking of the desugared code breaks the monadic abstraction. A side-effect-free, applicative code is normally compiled to (that is, desugars into) C or machine code. If the desugaring argument has any force, it may be applied just as well to the applicative code, leading to the conclusion that it all boils down to the machine code and hence all programming is imperative.
  >
  > [...] From the personal experience, I have noticed that the mistakes I make when writing monadic code are exactly the mistakes I made when programming in C. Actually, monadic mistakes tend to be worse, because monadic notation (compared to that of a typical imperative language) is ungainly and obscuring.
  >
  > [Oleg Kiselyov](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.06544) (page 21 of 26).
- > The most difficult construct for students to understand is the monad. I introduce `IO` without mentioning monads.
  >
  > [Olaf Chitil.](https://wiki.haskell.org/index.php?title=Haskell_in_education&oldid=63321)

More generally:

- > Still, today, over 25 years after the introduction of the concept of monads to the world of functional programming, beginning functional programmers struggle to grasp the concept of monads. This struggle is exemplified by the numerous blog posts about the effort of trying to learn about monads. From our own experience we notice that even at university level, bachelor level students often struggle to comprehend monads and consistently score poorly on monad-related exam questions.
  >
  > Considering that the concept of monads is not likely to disappear from the functional programming landscape any time soon, it is vital that we, as the functional programming community, somehow overcome the problems novices encounter when first studying monads.
  >
  > [Tim Steenvoorden, Jurriën Stutterheim, Erik Barendsen and Rinus Plasmeijer.](https://pms.cs.ru.nl/iris-diglib/src/getContent.php?id=2017-Steenvoorden-SupportLearning)

If only there was another way to specify "*a guaranteed order of execution*" in Haskell, while keeping the ability to separate regular Haskell definitions from those involved in I/O (and its observable effects) - translating this variation of [Philip Wadler](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.91.3579&rep=rep1&type=pdf)'s `echo`:

```ml
val echoML    : unit -> unit
fun echoML () = let val c = getcML () in
                if c = #"\n" then
                  ()
                else
                  let val _ = putcML c in
                  echoML ()
                end

fun putcML c  = TextIO.output1(TextIO.stdOut,c);
fun getcML () = valOf(TextIO.input1(TextIO.stdIn));
```

...could then be as simple as:

```hs
echo :: OI -> ()                         
echo u = let !(u1:u2:u3:_) = partsOI u in
         let !c = getChar u1 in          
         if c == '\n' then               
           ()                            
         else                            
           let !_ = putChar c u2 in      
           echo u3
```

where:

```hs
data OI  -- abstract

foreign import ccall "primPartOI" partOI :: OI -> (OI, OI)
                      ⋮

foreign import ccall "primGetCharOI" getChar :: OI -> Char
foreign import ccall "primPutCharOI" putChar :: Char -> OI -> ()
                      ⋮
```

and:

```hs
partsOI         :: OI -> [OI]
partsOI u       =  let !(u1, u2) = partOI u in u1 : partsOI u2
```

How would this work? At run-time, `Main.main` receives an initial `OI` [*pseudo-data*](https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/article-pdf/31/3/243/1157325/310243.pdf) value as an argument:

```hs
module Main(main) where

main            :: OI -> ()
          ⋮
```

...from which other `OI` values are produced, using `partOI` or `partsOI`. All you have to do is ensure each new `OI` value is used at most *once*, in each call to an `OI`-based definition, foreign or otherwise. In return, you get back a plain ordinary result - it isn't e.g. paired with some odd abstract state, or requires the use of a <s>callback</s> continuation, etc.

Using `OI`, instead of the unit type `()` like Standard ML does, means we can avoid *always* having to use the monadic interface:

> Once you're in the `IO` monad, you're stuck there forever, and are reduced to Algol-style imperative programming.
>
> [Robert Harper](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/05/01/of-course-ml-has-monads).

But if you really `do` need it:

```hs
type IO a       =  OI -> a

unitIO          :: a -> IO a
unitIO x        =  \ u -> let !_ = partOI u in x

bindIO          :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
bindIO m k      =  \ u -> let !(u1, u2) = partOI u in
                          let !x        = m u1 in
                          let !y        = k x u2 in
                          y

                      ⋮
```

So, monadic types aren't *always* needed - there are other interfaces out there:

> LML had a fully fledged implementation of oracles running of a multi-processor (a Sequent Symmetry) back in ca 1989. The description in [the Fudgets thesis](https://cth.altocumulus.org/%7Ehallgren/Thesis/toc.html) refers to this implementation. It was fairly pleasant to work with and quite practical.
>
> [...]
>
> These days everything is done with monads so other solutions are sometimes forgotten.
>
> [Lennart Augustsson](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1665#comment-20339) (2006).

---

Wait a moment: since it so closely resembles Standard ML's direct use of effects, is this approach and its use of *pseudo-data* referentially transparent?

Absolutely - just find a suitable definition of "*referential transparency*"; [there's plenty to choose from...](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.469.6920&rep=rep1&type=pdf)